# Properly handle a URL that matches two routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have two URLs like below:

```
http://domain.com/api/locations/codeforlocation
http://domain.com/api/locations/import
```

In my routing file I have the below lines in the same order:

```
app.put('api/locations/:location', require('./api/locations.js').put);
app.put('api/locations/import, require('./api/locationsimport.js').put);
```

But when I call "http://domain.com/api/locations/import" this will always call this "http://domain.com/api/locations/codeforlocation" only

How do I differentiate my path parameters?

Comment: You don't do routing in NodeJS at all. You do it in some layer on top of it, such as (guessing from your sample code) ExpressJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch around the order of handlers:

```
app.put('api/locations/import', require('./api/locationsimport.js').put);
app.put('api/locations/:location', require('./api/locations.js').put);
```

Routes are executed in the order they're defined, so you need to define the more specific ones first.